# combinations of k-tuple from n elements set by recursive

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void SubSetNum(bool * select, int*a, int selectk, int k, int selectn, int n )// depthk to 
{
    if(k>n) return;
    if(selectn==n)
    {   
        if(selectk==k)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                if(select[i]==true)
                    cout<<a[i];
            cout<<endl;
        }
        return;
    }

    select[selectk]=false;
    SubSetNum(select,a,selectk,k,selectn+1,n);
    select[selectk]=true;
    SubSetNum(select,a,selectk+1,k,selectn+1,n);

}

int main()
{
    int k=3;
    int n=5;
    int a[]={1,5,8,10,13};
    //while(cin>>k)
    {
        bool *select=new bool[n];
        memset(select,0,sizeof(bool)*n);
        SubSetNum(select,a,0,k,0,n);
        delete []select;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This a question, that I want to get k elements from n elements set.

But it prints out incorrect answer? I am always confused when I design recursive algorithms...Especially the parameter of functions, if or not return value, and so on, thus I always try to forcely remember the code in textbook.

Comment: What's the expected output? What output are you getting?

Comment: `bool *select=new bool[n];`...why use `new` when you can use `vector`?

Comment: 158
158
158
158
15810
15810
158
15810
158
158

Comment: What is the correct answer? We do not know what you want this program to do.

Comment: yes, I used vector before, but maybe it will make program more complex. I have read textbook about backtracking algorithm framework, they intend to use a array to record status of each element

Comment: I want to print the answer  158
1510
1513
1810
1813
11013
5810
5813
51013
81013   that is C(5,3) of five elements

Comment: @user3766015 can you try to add a pseudocode for your code first, it will help us to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
select[selectk]=false;                                                                   
...
select[selectk]=true;
```

It should be this:

```
select[selectn]=false;
...
select[selectn]=true;
```

I believe the cause of the mistake was a failure to remember what the variables represent. The variable `selectn` is the index of the element being included or excluded. The variable `selectk` is the number of elements already included. It does not make sense to use `selectk` as an index into `a`.

Comment: oh, yes, really thanks for your help, I always consider mistakes on recursive exit condition, but miss such a obvious mistakes, thank you: )